# cannot merge truststore with keytool

Tags: java, ssl, keystore, keytool

I'm trying to merge two jks files by executing

`keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore somefile_src.jks -destkeystore somefile_dst.keystore  -srcstorepass somepassword -deststorepass somepassword`

but I get `keytool error: java.io.IOException: keystore password was incorrect`

However for both source and destination truststore, I can view the contents with `keytool -v -list -keystore <path to jks file>` with the passwords I'm using when trying to merge the jks files, so the password should be correct.

I was wondering if there are any potential reasons why I get this error when trying to merge the jks files
​

Comment: Remember there are potentially 2 levels of passwords: overall keystore and private key-specific passwords. You probably have the latter wrong.

Comment: Check out this website for a solution: https://www.webfarmr.eu/2010/04/import-pkcs12-private-keys-into-jks-keystores-using-java-keytool/

Comment: @DavidBrossard this was helpful thanks. Executing ```keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore somefile_src.jks -destkeystore somefile_dst.keystore``` and then providing password when asked in commandline ```Enter source keystore password:``` , ```Enter destination keystore password:``` worked for me